# Attempting to add a WCF Web Server Reference Provider fails because it tries to create directories for DNC directories that already exist

Tags: wcf, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I can go through the initial process of trying to add the reference and it looks okay:

[image]

It starts the scaffolding process:

[image]

But then it fails because it's trying to create some DNC directories that already exist. I don't even know why it's trying to create those directories in Program Files. That seems odd:

[image: wcf]

Any ideas on what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t run into this similar issue ever, I reckon that there is something wrong with the compatibility between the Core framework and WCF. Have you tried to add the service reference in other machines?  if the error only happen in this computer, I suggest you re-install the Dotnet Core SDK.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download
I suggest you submit the issue to the official repository.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.